# .NET MultipartFormDataContent don't send filename param in Content-Disposition header?

Tags: c#, http-headers, .net-4.5, multipartform-data

I have a C# program (.NET 4.5) that uses MultipartFormDataContent to send data to a web server. A file is added with this code:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), "file0", fPath);
```

This version of MultipartFormDataContent.Add has these parameters:

```
public void Add(HttpContent content, string name, string fileName);
```

This version of the Add method is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.multipartformdatacontent.add?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_MultipartFormDataContent_Add_System_Net_Http_HttpContent_System_String_System_String_). The official MDN directives for Content-Disposition headers [are documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition). The reality: when the request arrives to the server, the form part has these headers:

```
{'name': 'Content-Disposition', 'value': 'form-data', 'params': {}}
```

Both `name` and `filename` are missing from the headers! If I use the two parameter version of the Add method:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(fPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
content.Add(new StreamContent(stream), fPath);
```

then the header arrives to the server such as:

```
{'name': 'Content-Disposition', 'value': 'form-data', 'params': {'name': 'c:\\temp\test.txt'}}
```

In other words: the two parameter version sets the name of the field correctly. The three parameter version not just forgets to send the `filename` param, but it also vaporizes the `name` param.

For comparison, this is what I see when I POST a similar multipart/form-data from web page using Firefox:

```
{'name': 'Content-Disposition', 'value': 'form-data', 'params': {'name': 'file', 'filename': 'test.txt'}}
{'name': 'Content-Type', 'value': 'text/plain', 'params': {}}
```

Am I doing something wrong? **Is it really a bug in .NET/C#?** I really need to know the filename on the server side, and it **must** be compatible with other requests sent from other browsers. So I can't just add extra headers and send the filename there. It has to be compatible with other browsers. How am I supposed to send the filename from C#?

Comment: There is an nginx sitting between the C# client and the actual web server but I guess that does not matter.